# Transparent overlaping path when creating font with Illustrator and FontSelf

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, otf

I'm trying to create a glyph font with FontSelf (https://www.fontself.com/) and Adobe Illustrator but I'm running into somes problems.

As you can see on the screen capture below, on the exported font, the overlaping path are showing as transparent as if they were negating each other ?

Screen capture of the finsihed font exhibing the overlaping paths problem:

[image: Screen capture of the finsihed font exhibing the overlaping paths problem]

I've tried to insert the shapes in FontSelf as outlined path, expanded shapes, coupond path. But in some case part of the illustration simply are not being imported in FontSelf, or they exhibit the "overlaping path problem".

What whould you guys advise ?

Thanks

Damien

Comment: I've used an online font converter to turn the .otf file into a .ttf and it did solve my problem.

As you can see, I don't really know what am doing and would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction in order to prevent that sort of problem next time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple known issues that we will fix soon (one is an Illustrator bug with specific compound shapes and the other is due to how we handle boolean operations in Fontself - when we automatically merge some shapes that overlap).

Until then, you can use the Pathfinder Union feature to ensure there is no overlap. If the error persists (due to the Illustrator bug), you can also create a dummy object (like a square), merge it with you glyphs using Pathfinder > Union, and then delete the square.

This will be all be cleaned up in the next big update of Fontself. Stay tuned...